# How to fix a javafx.fxml.LoadException?

Tags: java, javafx, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to make javafx login window, and I followed some tutorial, but it gives me a strange bug...

src/main/java/scripter/nukkit/PlayerTool/MainApplication.java

```
package scripter.nukkit.PlayerTool;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.fxml.*;

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public class MainApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("MainApplication.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 275);

        primaryStage.setTitle("FXML Welcome");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

src/main/java/scripter/nukkit/PlayerTool/MainController.java

```
package scripter.nukkit.PlayerTool;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public class MainController {
    @FXML
    private Text actiontarget;

    @FXML
    protected void handleSubmitButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        actiontarget.setText("Sign in button pressed");
    }
}
```

src/main/resources/MainApplication.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<GridPane fx:controller="scripter.nukkit.PlayerTool.MainController" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
    <padding>
        <Insets top="25" right="25" bottom="10" left="25"/>
    </padding>
    <Text text="Welcome" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnSpan="2"/>

    <Label text="User Name:" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>

    <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>

    <Label text="Password:" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>

    <PasswordField fx:id="passwordField" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>
    <HBox spacing="10" alignment="bottom_right" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
        <Button text="Sign In" onAction="#handleSubmitButtonAction"/>
    </HBox>
    <Text fx:id="actiontarget" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="6"/>
</GridPane>
```

error report

```
Exception in thread "Thread-7" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: n Source)


    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:103)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:922)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at scripter.nukkit.PlayerTool.MainApplication.start(MainApplication.java:19)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scripter.nukkit.PlayerTool.MainController
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:920)
    ... 22 more
```

and I tested

```
Class.forName("scripter.nukkit.PlayerTool.MainController")
```

but it worked.
Why it can't find class?!